# Trouble adding managed property to search results

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, fast-search

I have some managed properties like this:

[image: hehehe test..]

The central admin for my team created a property with a name like "DEPT ID". In adding to the columns list (e.g., `<Column Name="ModifiedBy"/>`). Adding `<Column Name="DEPT ID"/>` (or any other variations I can think of) just don't return anything. How does SharePoint store column names like these (all I know is that it isn't the internal name..).

Comment: DEPT ID is not possible as an internal name of a column, nor as a Managed Property (blanks are not allowed)

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's what's listed in my schema and what shows in the dropdown. I'm guessing it likely means that he either changed it to some other value or it failed to be created properly. Thank you.

Comment: The internal name is probably different than the display name

Comment: Can you ask what name they used? The crawled property is based on the Column Name, so if you actually used a space in your column name it will be "ows_DEPTx0020xID". Which is why you should never use spaces in column names. But you cannot guess the MP Name because a human created it.

Comment: The relationship dance from column to crawled property to managed property is not an easy one until you have worked with it a while. Search is a different beast more or less fully decoupled from the object model of SP.